# Map View in flutter

Tags: google-maps, mobile, view, dart, flutter

Is there any way how make normal Map View in flutter. I need to have map ready when user opens the app. Only thing I saw, is that apptree plugin, but I could only make the map appear after user taps the button (and fullscreen, I need to put it into container). Basicaly what I need is some Map Widget, is there any ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use some plugin like

https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view

flutter plugin for displaying google maps on iOS and Android

```
//Create an instance variable for the mapView
var _mapView = new MapView();


//Add a method to call to show the map.
void showMap() {
    _mapView.show(new MapOptions(showUserLocation: true));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is one of the drawbacks of choosing to render own components on GPU instead of using OEM solutions, they need to bake GMaps renderer over Flutter APIs and probably will, in the meanwhile, try this implementation: https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_map